# How to deploy NLP models on Azure?

Tags: azure, nlp, azure-web-app-service, chatbot

I am working on a project to create an AI Chatbot. For that, I have built an NLP model. After making the bot, I deployed this bot on Azure. But It is not responding to anything after getting messages from users. Whereas, It was working and answering correctly on localhost. Does anyone know the exact way of deploying NLP models on Azure? Any proper documentation will be highly appreciated.

You can find the Github repo here- [Link](https://github.com/shamim237/JarvisNLP)

Comment: [Use Cognitive Services with natural language processing (NLP) to enrich chat bot conversations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/choose-natural-language-processing-service), [Steps to Build and Deploy your NLP model as a Microservice on Azure](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-steps-to-build-and-deploy-your-nlp-model-as-a-microservice-on-azure-426ca77c66df) and [Create an NLP Language Understanding Bot with Azure Framework SDK C# & .NET](https://www.samarpaninfotech.com/blog/create-nlp-chatbot-with-azure-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

This could be the required documentation you are looking for deploying the NLP on azure platform [enter link description here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/fine-tune-natural-language-processing-models-using-azure-machine-learning-service/)